# Angular 7 - sort a table trs using ng-content projection

Tags: angular, angular7

**Tech**: Angular 7, using ng-content projection inside an angular cli app.

**Outcome I want:**

I want my tr's to be sorted by a column e.g. column 1, 2 or 3.
This is one so I have a reusable component.

**My Component:**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'ls-table-body',
  template: `
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./table-body.component.scss']
})
export class TableBodyComponent {
  @Input() public isLoading: boolean;
  @Input() public isData: boolean;
  @Input() public message = 'No Data Available';
}
```

**My Component being used:**

```
         <ls-table-body>
          <tr class="child-row">
            <td>aaaa</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="child-row">
            <td>dddd</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr class="child-row">
            <td>bbbbb</td>
            <td>data</td>
            <td>data</td>
          </tr>
        </ls-table-body>
```

**Note:** I'm not too sure if its possible to access the **@contentChild** using a **querylist** and then reorder the rows.

I'm also open to other options.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you hold your data in an array and bind it to an input property of the child component?

Comment: Because I need to project the tds as some contain math calcs and icons etc. So ideally I want to be able to reorder - maybe theirs a third party tool I can add to sort?

Comment: Okay, I see where you are coming from. I don't know how you could achieve this with content projection, but I think it's possible with ng-templates. What's the criteria you want to sort the list by?

Comment: I want to sort by heading names - so I will eventually pass in an input to this component stating the column number e.g. col 1,2 or 3 to orderby and another input for type e.g. asc or desc